# Why are variables not instantiated when referenced from onSelectionChanged via a custom edit text?

Tags: android, kotlin

Any variables that are referenced in `onSelectionChanged` are null according to the debugger, and if I run my sample app with the following added to a simple layout my app crashes with a nullpointer.

```
 <com.dummy.DummyEditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

The simplest example of a custom `AppCompatEditText`

```
package com.dummy

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText

class DummyEditText : AppCompatEditText {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    private val a = String()
    override fun onSelectionChanged(selStart: Int, selEnd: Int) {
        a.toString()
    }
}
```

with the stacktrace

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.dummy.DummyEditText.onSelectionChanged(DummyEditText.kt:15)
2020-10-05 12:14:25.794 22859-22859/com.dummy E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:10744)
        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:13600)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1287)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:777)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:676)
        at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:96)
        at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:78)
        at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:153)
        at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:312)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6299)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6139)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:121)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1642)
        at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:87)
        at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:83)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:74)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:69)
        at com.dummy.DummyEditText.<init>(DummyEditText.kt:10)
```

So the question is why is the variable `a` null? It should have been instantiated when it is first referenced in the `onSelectionChanged` regardless of how `DummyEditText` is instantiated. What am I missing here?

Any pointers on what is going on are appreciated!

Comment: I can only partially replicate your issue - I get the "Error inflating class com.x.y.DummyEditText" before I got the NPE, is this the case for you as well? I needed to add `super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd)` in order for code to compile at all

Comment: Yes that's the case for me as well that the top error is that inflation description but when you look further down you see that it is caused by the NPE. Strange that you couldn't get it to compile without the super call. I don't have that problem in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On debugging, I found out that `onSelectionChanged` is called before the `init` block is run.

As mentioned in [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors):

> During an instance initialization, the initializer blocks are executed in the same order as they appear in the class body, interleaved with the property initializers

The properties haven't been initialized when `OnSelectionChanged` is called.

So, I believe, what happening is that in one of the superclasses, some code in the constructor must be causing `onSelectionChanged` to be called. So before any of the properties are initialized the `onSelectionChanged` is called and your field is therefore null.

Here is a sample to replicate the scenario:

```kotlin
open class Parent {
    init {
        demo()
    }    
    
    open fun demo() {
        print("Base class function called")
    }
}

class Child() : Parent() {
    
    val demoText = "12345"
    override fun demo() {
        super.demo()

        println(demoText.toString()) // This line will throw a NPE as demoText is not yet instantiated
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, that makes a lot of sense. Also an easy source of bugs since the implementation details of the OS spill across can therefore potentially affect the stability of the app. Especially as implementation changes over different versions of Android and devices. Thanks for putting the time into the answer and a very helpful, demo of the problem.